# "This app relies on Fabric" when Installing fabric with CocoaPod

Tags: ios, macos, cocoapods, twitter-fabric

Fabric: This app relies on Fabric. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
install Fabric.app then ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.

I'm trying to install Twitter's Fabric on a different computer than the one I used to register using cocoaPods.

http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Fabric/1.2.3/

> Installing Use Fabric Mac app to configure the components you need
>   (required for this pod to work). Remove all frameworks from project
>   which were added by Fabric app. Add pods to Podfile
>
> pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.2' # required pod 'Fabric/Crashlytics', '~> 1.2'
>   pod 'Fabric/MoPub', '~> 1.2' pod 'Fabric/Twitter', '~> 1.2' Then run
>   pod install.
>
> Change the path in Run Script Build command to:
>
> ./Pods/Fabric/Fabric.framework/run YOUR_API_KEY YOUR_BUILD_SECRET

Does anyone has an idea where to download "Fabric Mac app" and why it is needed ?

Comment: Are you even read what there sad? Did you try go to https://fabric.io?

Comment: actually yes, but but they have an app kind of website that doesn't let you go where you want. i contacted the support to get the direct URL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Contacted Fabric support:
Downloaded the "app" here https://fabric.io/downloads  and it fixed the problem.

Comment: is Fabric.io free? did you pay any money or will you?

Comment: @de_la_vega_66 I'm mostly using Crashlytics, so far it's free.

Comment: This is strange. I've moved from the clunky regular installation of Fabric to the cocoa pods method, so I've already had Fabric installed. But apparently I still needed to reinstall Fabric
 +1

Comment: reinstalling the fabric app solved the problem but it gets corrupted after sometimes. So need to place an app again in Application folder